# Display Product More Information In product Category Listing Page

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, blocks, phtml

**i want to display product "More information" in catalog category page.**

I copy that code from

> `/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml`

```
    <?php $_additional = $block->getAdditionalData($_product);?>
    <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
        <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
                <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('More Information') ?></caption>
                    <tbody>
                     <?php foreach ((array)$_additional as $_data): ?>
                        <tr>
                         <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></th>
                            <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
```

And add it in

> `vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

But it not work, because it use different block than the list.phtml file.

**What is the best solution to do that?**

Comment: please remove cache and then try to reload. because you are using correct block

Comment: @user3328090, did you get a solution ?

Comment: @RonakChauhan list.phtml uses `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` and attributes.phtml uses `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes`

Comment: @Pawan no, i haven't find a solution yet.